# Ruby - Undefined method 'has_key?' on ternary assignment

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm getting the following error on Ruby when I try to assign a string to a variable:

```
undefined method 'has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The code that generates the error is the following:

```
uri = !@meta.has_key?("offset") ? "#{@@user_uri}?order=asc" : "#{@@user_uri}?per_page=#{per_page}&page=#{@meta['offset']}?order=asc"
```

If I remove the assignment and replace it with a puts, it works as expected

```
puts !@meta.has_key?("offset") ? "#{@@user_uri}?order=asc" : "#{@@user_uri}?per_page=#{per_page}&page=#{@meta['offset']}?order=asc"
> http://example.com/users?order=asc
```

Any idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you use `puts`, `@meta` has a different value. Please double check.

In any case, why not just make sure that `@meta` is not `nil` before trying to treat it like a `Hash`?

```
return if @meta.nil?
uri = !@meta.key?("offset") ? "#{@@user_uri}?order=asc" : "#{@@user_uri}?per_page=#{per_page}&page=#{@meta['offset']}?order=asc"
```

I changed `has_key?` for key? as `has_key?` [has been deprecated](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43765)

Comment: Thanks for the deprecated warning.
Indeed, the value of @meta was changed elsewhere. Now I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning to `return` if `@meta` is `nil`. Wouldn't it be better to allow the exception if `@meta` is never to be `nil`, or to deal with that case if `nil` is a possibility?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that is another approach he could take.